# SQL insert into where columns exist

Tags: sql, csv, if-statement, insert, exists

I am having trouble with a SQL insert statement.

Currently the Insert statement is used to transfer data from a .CSV file into a SQL table, but the contents of the .CSV file can vary i.e. it may contain different columns from that of the previous.

The statement that I use to aquire the data from the .CSV files supports the different columns as it creates a temporary table exactly as the .CSV appears.

The Insert statement that I currently use is:

```
INSERT INTO RTCU(ItemDATE, ItemTIME, SITENAME, GENSETNAME, GENSET_SN, REASON, EVENT, RPM, Pwr
                 ,Gfrq ,Vg1 ,Vg2 ,Vg3 ,Vg12 ,Vg23 ,Vg31, Ig1, Ig2, Ig3, Mfrq, Vm1, Vm2, Vm3
                 ,Vm12 ,Vm23 ,Vm31 ,BIN ,BOUT ,Mode ,CCpres ,OilLev
                 ,ActDem ,OilT ,AirInT ,RecAT ,JWTout ,JWTin ,JWGKin ,CylA1 ,CylA2 ,CylA3 ,CylA4 ,CylA5
                 ,CylA6 ,CylB1 ,CylB2 ,CylB3 ,CylB4 ,CylB5 ,CylB6 ,ActPwr ,kWhour ,Runhrs ,VRO)      
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,ItemDATE,103), ItemTIME, SITENAME, GENSETNAME, GENSET_SN, REASON, EVENT, RPM, Pwr
                 ,Gfrq ,Vg1 ,Vg2 ,Vg3 ,Vg12 ,Vg23 ,Vg31, Ig1, Ig2, Ig3, Mfrq, Vm1, Vm2, Vm3
                 ,Vm12 ,Vm23 ,Vm31 ,BIN ,BOUT ,Mode ,CCpres ,OilLev
                 ,ActDem ,OilT ,AirInT ,RecAT ,JWTout ,JWTin ,JWGKin ,CylA1 ,CylA2 ,CylA3 ,CylA4 ,CylA5
                 ,CylA6 ,CylB1 ,CylB2 ,CylB3 ,CylB4 ,CylB5 ,CylB6 ,ActPwr ,kWhour ,Runhrs ,VRO
FROM tmpDATA
```

But as you can see the columns that I copy are fixed, so what if one of my .CSV files has a column "HeatMeter" how would I go about copying this column into the RTCU table?

Thanks in advance!!
Neil

Comment: If your target table doesn't have that field, you can't insert that field into the table. For data to be inserted into a field, that field must exist. So, are you asking how to add a field to an existing table? Or are you asking how to insert `table1.fieldX` into `table2.fieldY`?  At the moment the question is `How do I fit this square peg in this round hole?` but I think we need to be more clear on your needs to understand what approach may actually help you.

Comment: The target table will have the column but the source table may or may not have that column. So for example Source A may have 'Pwr, RPM, Volts, Freq, Mode' columns where Source B may have 'Pwr, RPM, Volts, Freq, Mode, CCpres, OilLev' and Result A+B will have 'Pwr, RPM, Volts, Freq, Mode, CCpres, OilLev' so how do I ensure that the different contents of both Source A and B are copied into the result?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain that I understand your needs, but here is my best guess...

You have a destination table...

```
 ID | val_1 | val_2 | val_3
```

You have a source table...

```
 ID | val_1 | val_3
```

And you have a second source table...

```
 ID | val_2 | val_3
```

You want to insert the data from the two different sources into the destination table....

One option is to specify default values on the different columns...

```
CREATE TABLE destination (
  id      INT,
  val_1   INT DEFAULT(-1),
  val_2   INT DEFAULT(-2),
  val_3   INT DEFAULT(-3)
)

-- val3 is not specified in this insert
-- This means that it will appear as -3 for all the inserted rows
------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO destination (id, val_1, val_2)
SELECT id, val_1, val_2 FROM source1

-- val1 is not specified in this insert
-- This means that it will appear as -1 for all the inserted rows
------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO destination (id, val_2, val_3)
SELECT id, val_2, val_3 FROM source2
```

Another option is to simply hard code what value you want to appear in the 'missing' fields...

```
-- source1 does not have a val_3 field, so we hard-code the insert
-- to always put NULL in that field.
-------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO destination (id, val_1, val_2, val3)
SELECT id, val_1, val_2, NULL  FROM source1

-- source2 does not have a val_1 field, so we hard-code the insert
-- to always put 0 in that field.
-------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO destination (id, val_1, val_2, val_3)
SELECT id, 0,  val_2, val_3 FROM source2
```

Any value can be used as a default or hard-coded value.

Comment: Dems, I don't think that this will work as the source table will always have the same name tmpDATA. This tmpDATA table is created dynamically depending on what is contained in the CSV file. So for every column that exists in the CSV the column is created in the tmpDATA table. All of the CSV will have some common columns that never change as above in my question but there will also be variable columns that may or may not exist in the tmpDATA table. Such as: INSERT INTO RTCU(ItemDATE, ItemTIME, Variable1) SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,ItemDATE,103), ItemTIME, (IF EXISTS (Variable1)) FROM tmpDATA

Comment: @NeilRutherford - That is why in the above examples there are two different insert statements. When inserting into the destination table the code *must* specify what values go where. If the source schema is different each time, the insert statement must be different each time. You have three basic choices: 1. Enforce a rule that ensures all fields exist in your CSV (even if the value is a blank). 2. Manually code a different insert statement each time you recieve a file. 3. Write code (in sql or another language) that writes the new SQL Insert statement for you *(known as dynamic SQL)*.